# Unable to see entire Sitecore content tree on selecting any media library item

Tags: media-library

Below is the Sitecore tree structure in my project.

[image]

When I click on any item in the media library(for e.g. here Test1 item). I'm unable to see the entire content tree. Refer below image for the issue that I'm facing.

[image]

Can someone help provide a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on the Sitecore Icon present on the top left in **Content Editor**
then navigate to:

Application options ▶ View(2nd tab) ▶ Check the `Show Entire Content Tree` check box.